# "Where are the eggs?"

Tags: phrase-usage

Shopping, I ask a customer service person where I can find eggs to buy. And I go:

> "Excuse me, where are the eggs?"

Now, I am not sure, but I suspect that this is not the right way to ask the question. It sounds a little stupid, as if I were asking my spouse where the eggs I plan to cook for breakfast are.

Is that  how you ask the question?

Comment: If you find your sentence too short and simple you can ask: Where can I find eggs.

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with "Excuse me, where are the eggs?" (Well, when spoken. When written, it's a run-on sentence and the comma should be a full stop. But, unless you're [Victor Borge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qf_TDuhk3No), the person you're speaking to won't know how you're punctuating.)

Answer (score 16):

As a native (American) English speaker, I see no problems with your question (or the the other answers). I'd say the the "Excuse me" softens the question sufficiently to use it with a person you don't know.

However, if you wish to soften the question further, you can use the [subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood). Adding a degree of "hypothetical" makes it even less of a demand.

> Excuse me, where would I find the eggs?

or

> Pardon me, where would the eggs be?

Another approach for softening requests is to ask about the request, rather than request directly. (This is seen in using "Pardon me, but do you know the time?", rather than the more direct "What time is it?")

> Excuse me, do you know where the eggs are?

Alternatively, you can simply state your situation, and rely on the listener following social conventions and answering the implied question.

> Pardon me, I'm looking for the eggs.

Comment: All your suggestions are perfectly grammatical but the first two sound very old-fashioned. They sound like something from the 1950s or even earlier.

Comment: Is the definite article used correctly here? I'm not a native speaker, but I would use no article here, because I wouldn't mean some specific eggs.

Comment: @nightcoder While you can omit it, the definite article is fine here. "The" is used to refer to [items whose identity is established](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article), from being either the only one or the only *relevant* one from context. -- You could consider "the eggs" as an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) for "the eggs which your store is selling". A joking person might answer "Where would I find eggs?" with "Under a chicken!", but that response doesn't work well if "the" is included.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, that is **exactly** what you are doing, asking both the customer service person and your spouse

> **Where are the eggs?**

is correct in both instances, but you might only use **excuse me** in the supermarket.

Other concise ways to ask are

> **What aisle are the eggs?**
>   (The) **eggs are?** (where) *(looking lost)*
>   **Eggs?** *(with optional pointing in some direction)*
>   **Which way are the eggs?**

Don't worry about just saying **eggs** staff know that if you are asking for help it's usually to find something and they tend to be very busy scurrying around so brevity is appreciated

For those who seem befuddled by using shorthand, the reason why it works is because the situation calls for a single objective with an unambiguous description. In this case it's finding a location. Other examples are

> **Men's Room?**  to find the restroom
>   **Check please** to get the bill in a restaurant
>   **Trafalgar Square?** to confirm a destination when getting on a bus in London

Comment: Or if you ordered a [full **English** (breakfast)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_breakfast) and the waitress brought you a plate with bacon, sausages, fried bread, tomatoes, mushrooms, etc., but ***no fried / scrambled / poached eggs***.

Comment: In the US (as the answer provided by TRomano indicates), one asks: "excuse me, what aisle are the eggs in?". Your suggestion that I could ask, "excuse me, where are the eggs?" Is that British English?

Comment: Nope, I've used "Where are the eggs?" in the States without any problems, the answer that comes back tends to be "in aisle 6" or "over by the dairy section" or something like that. The reason I don't use "in what aisle?" is because it may be along the side somewhere.  You can also use "What aisle are the eggs?" to find them

Comment: @Peter. Thank you, Peter. "What aisle are the eggs?" -- without a preposition at all?

Comment: Yes,  just like in a department store "What floor is men's?"

Comment: To my ear, "What aisle are the eggs?" sounds like it's missing a preposition. I much prefer adding an _in_ to that question: "What aisle are the eggs in?"

Comment: I agree that adding *in* to the end sounds better, but if I'm around.. *those* type of people, I may find myself using the phrase "In which aisle are the eggs located?"

Comment: As a native American English speaker, I've never added the word "aisle" to a question about where something is in the grocery store. Regarding eggs specifically, they are often located in a refrigerated case that is not even in an aisle, but in one of the major sections like diary.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me (not native speaker, btw), but hearing "*Eggs are?*" in a supermarket is strange for me.

Comment: -1 The asker is already confident enough to say, "Excuse me, where are the eggs?" Given that, I don't understand at all why you spend more than half of your answer suggesting phrases such as "Eggs are?" and "Eggs?" Those are far below the asker's level and only one step above mime. They do nothing to help the asker _learn English_, which is surely the goal here.

Comment: Because it gets used in real life.  Granted the usage may be more AmE than BrE.

Comment: It's hard to imagine a native speaker saying "Eggs are?" in this context.

Comment: I agree that *Eggs are?* might not fit everyone's personality. But I can still picture people saying it.

Answer (score 5):

In an American supermarket you could ask

> What aisle are the eggs in?

Comment: We could also ask "Where are the eggs?" or simply "Eggs?"  Context is king.

Comment: *Where can I find the eggs?* may be just a tinge more polite than *Where are the eggs?* all else being equal, though tone of voice and body language are more important.

Comment: There's usually fairly loud music coming out of the ceiling speakers, so I've whittled my supermarket questions down to the bare essentials:  "Aluminum foil?" -- Aisle 6.  "Thanks".

Comment: Maybe it's a dialect/local thing, but "eggs **in** an isle" sounds wrong.  Eggs are **on** isle 10.

Comment: In Texas, would you ask "What aisle are eggs *on*?"

Comment: Everywhere I've been in the US uses "in" not "on" with "aisle"

Comment: In Britain you would ask "In which aisle are the eggs?", so that you don't end a sentence with a preposition.

Comment: @Chenmunka: Are you saying that Brits naturally avoid ending the sentence with a preposition?

Comment: @TRomano: Most of them, yes.  Although, of course, not everybody.

Answer (score 2):

In British-English, "What aisle are the eggs in" sounds quite jarring. I would use "Which aisle are the eggs in?".

"Excuse me, where are the eggs?" is perfectly fine though.